# Android: lock WiFi to an SSID and prevent scanning

Tags: android, tcp, wifi

I have an app connecting to a single predefined SSID which is a standalone AP without internet access. I can scan for it, connect to it, build tcp connection and stream data. My problem is that if WiFi based location service is enabled the connection periodically get lost and have to reconnect.

I always see this line in the log just before tcp teardown:
D AlarmManager com.google.android.location in backlist, type is 0

I cannot judge if this is the cause or result of the problem. How could I make sure WiFi connection will not be disturbed by the system?
Is it possible to prevent other activities and/or the system to issue scans while my app is running?